# MVC5 automatically split IEnumerable<primitive> Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

let's say I got an Action with the following signature:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(IEnumerable<string> myList){ .. }
```

and AnotherAction:

```
public ActionResult AnotherAction() {
    var myListEntries = LoadFromSomewhere().ToList<string>();

    return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", new { myList = String.Join(";", MyListEntries) });
}
```

Is there any way to tell the first action that it has to apply a separator on the incoming values?
Or do I have to use TempData[] or (in HTML) multiple Input fields?

Comment: Why don't you call it with `return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", new { myList = myListEntries })`?

Comment: Because calling it with new { myList = myListEntries } will end up in SomeAction(IEnumerable<string> myList) with myList[0] = "System.Collection.Generic..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So calling

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", new { myList = myListEntries });
```

doesn't work, cause the result is that your action will receive a list with one entry which contains what you would get from `myList.ToString()` what only returns the type name which is quite useless.

So as you already guessed you have to insert some kind of string representation which MVC automatically can convert back into a list object. To receive this you should not use `String.Join()`, but maybe give JSON a try:

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", new { myList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList) });
```